# What are the steps to publish a react native library with native codes (Java and Objective C)

Tags: react-native, npm

I want to publish a react native library to npm with native codes (Java and Objective C). I have created a react native app and the native modules and native UI components are working fine in the app but I don't know how to publish my code as a react native library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have completed all the tests, you can do this with a simple library.

that is [create-react-native-library](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-builder-bob/blob/main/README.md)

This is shown in the [official document of react-native.](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-setup)

You can also use [create-react-native-module](https://github.com/brodybits/create-react-native-module), a library with multiple added functions based on `react-native-create-library`

Comment: hi , i have written native modules which internally uses xcframework for ios and aar for android, i don't know how to include them in NPM package. they are local frameworks.

Comment: @Matrix hi, you can see this url https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-npm-registry

Answer (score 0):

1 - run  **npx create-react-native-library@latest library-name**

2 - then run npm i on root diretory

3 - then if you want to make UI library then simply add your components in
src folder and if you want to make native modules then follow
[https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rc8P1.png)

4 - after you done you can test with example folder given in the project

5 - After that just do npm login and then npm publish to publish your module
in npm registry